# Leaking screen drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, memory-leaks, drawrect

I need to draw grid to UIViewControllers.view. For a some reason my routine allocates huge amount of memory (15 to 20 megabytes) and it does not release it correctly. If I refresh grid programmatically my app allocates more and more memory and eventually it will crash. Before crash, it receives many didReceiveMemoryWarnings. If I commented out following code app works as expected.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.lineColor setStroke];
    NSInteger horizontalLineScaling = roundf((float)(self.bounds.size.height-30)/((float)(self.endTime-self.startTime)*4));
    // horizontal lines
    CGFloat dash1[] = {2.0, 0, 2.0};
    UIBezierPath *horizontal1 = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [horizontal1 setLineDash:dash1 count:1 phase:2];
    [horizontal1 setLineWidth:1];
    for (float y = horizontalLineScaling; y < self.bounds.size.height; y += horizontalLineScaling*2) {
        [horizontal1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(1, y+30)];
        [horizontal1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, y+30)];
    };

    UIBezierPath *horizontal2 = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [horizontal2 setLineWidth:1];
    for (float y = 0; y < self.bounds.size.height; y += horizontalLineScaling*2) {
        [horizontal2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(1, y+30)];
        [horizontal2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, y+30)];
    };

    UIBezierPath *horizontal3 = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [horizontal3 setLineWidth:3];
    for (float y = 0; y < self.bounds.size.height; y += horizontalLineScaling*4) {
        [horizontal3 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(1, y+30)];
        [horizontal3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, y+30)];
    };
    // Frame
    UIBezierPath *screenFrame = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y+30, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
    // Vertical Lines
    UIBezierPath *vertical = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [vertical setLineWidth:2];
    [vertical moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width-5, 0)];
    [vertical addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width-5, 29)];
    [vertical moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width-2, 0)];
    [vertical addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width-2, 29)];

    [horizontal1 stroke];
    [horizontal2 stroke];
    [horizontal3 stroke];
    [screenFrame stroke];
    [vertical stroke];
}
```

Is there any way to draw grid without memory problems?

Comment: Is it an ARC project?

Comment: Where do you allocate and store the `view` that has this custom drawing function. Can you post relevant code?

Comment: @sha Thank you. It's funny how sometimes small push to the right direction can be crucial. I was copy-pasting my code to show and while I 'm doing it I realized it was a way too complicated. I spent whole day cleaning my code and it seems to work now. There was couple of retain circles. Because drawing routine allocated so much memory it seems to be guilty to this error.

Comment: Any way this seems to be solved now. Thank you everybody